# Form splitted into tabs in a page does not submit to servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp

Below is the code for my jsp page. I have a page where form is split into tabs. Have next previous buttons to navigate. What I want is to send the data from input fields to the servlet where I will put them in database.

But, how to do that?
I tried providing in button type submit just inside last tab, but that's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Real Estate</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->  
    <script src="js/crawler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Include SmartWizard CSS -->
<link href="css/smart_wizard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Optional SmartWizard theme -->
<link href="css/smart_wizard_theme_dots.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    marqueeInit({
        uniqueid : 'mycrawler2',
        style : {

        },
        inc : 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
        mouse : 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
        moveatleast : 2,
        neutral : 150,
        savedirection : true,
        random : true

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myInverseNavbar2"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">RoofandKey</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myInverseNavbar2">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-haspopup="true">Buy <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li
                                            style="color: blue; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 15px; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif">Residential</li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Under Construction Flats</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Ready to move flats</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">House/Villa</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Plots</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Owner Properties</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li
                                            style="color: blue; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 15px; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif">Commercial</li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Office Space</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Commertial Shops</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </ul></li>



                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-haspopup="true">Rent <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li
                                            style="color: blue; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 15px; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif">Residential</li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Flats</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">House/Villa</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">PG's</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Owner Properties</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li
                                            style="color: blue; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 15px; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif">Commercial</li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Office Space</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Commercial Shops</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="advertise.jsp" class="" role="button">Post
                            Property free </a></li>
                    <%
                        if (session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
                    %>
                    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><i
                            class="hd-dign"><img src="images/signin.png"></i>Sign in</a></li>
                    <%
                        } else {
                    %>
                    <li style="margin-top: 15px;">Welcume <%=session.getAttribute("username")%></li>
                    <li><form class="form-horizontal" method="post"
                            action="getlogout">
                            <input type="submit" value="logout">
                        </form></li>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>


                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                        aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                        Login/Registration</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8"
                                            style="border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2; padding-right: 30px;">
                                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                <li class="active"><a href="#Login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="Login">

                                                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="form1" method="post"
                                                        action="UserLogin">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Email</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <input type="email" name="txtmail" class="form-control"
                                                                    id="email1" placeholder="Email" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1"
                                                                class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Password</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <input type="password" name="txtpassword"
                                                                    class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                                                                    placeholder="Email" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                                                    Submit</button>
                                                                <a href="javascript:;">Forgot your password?</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                                                    <form action="UserRegister" method="post" role="form"
                                                        class="form-horizontal">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Name</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <div class="row">

                                                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                                        <input type="text" name="txtname" class="form-control"
                                                                            placeholder="Name" />
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="type" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Type</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">

                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                        <select name="txttype" class="form-control">
                                                                            <option>Seller</option>
                                                                            <option>Buyer</option>
                                                                            <option>Both</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Mobile</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <input type="mobile" name="txtmobile"
                                                                    class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Email</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <input type="email" name="txtmail" class="form-control"
                                                                    id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Gender</label>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                    <select name="txtgender" class="form-control">
                                                                        <option>Male</option>
                                                                        <option>Female</option>

                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                                Password</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <input type="password" name="txtpassword"
                                                                    class="form-control" id="password"
                                                                    placeholder="Password" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                                                    Save & Continue</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                                                    Cancel</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="OR" class="hidden-xs">OR</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="row text-center sign-with">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <h3>Sign in with</h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</a> <a
                                                            href="#" class="btn btn-danger"> Google</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>


            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <form action="index.jsp" id="myForm" role="form" data-toggle=""
            method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <!-- SmartWizard html -->
            <div id="smartwizard">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#step-1"><small>Email Address</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#step-2"><small>Name</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#step-3"><small>Address</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#step-4"><small>Terms and Conditions</small></a></li>
                </ul>

                <div>
                    <div id="step-1">
                        <h2>Your Email Address</h2>
                        <div id="form-step-0" role="form" data-toggle="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email address:</label> <input type="email"
                                    class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                                    placeholder="Write your email address" required>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="step-2">
                        <h2>Your Name</h2>
                        <div id="form-step-1" role="form" data-toggle="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control" name="name" id="email"
                                    placeholder="Write your name" required>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="step-3">
                        <h2>Your Address</h2>
                        <div id="form-step-2" role="form" data-toggle="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="address">Address</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address"
                                    rows="3" placeholder="Write your address..." required></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="step-4" class="">
                        <h2>Terms and Conditions</h2>
                        <p>Terms and conditions: Keep your smile :)</p>
                        <div id="form-step-3" role="form" data-toggle="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="terms">I agree with the T&C</label> <input
                                    type="checkbox" id="terms"
                                    data-error="Please accept the Terms and Conditions" required>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="button" for="button" id="button" value="Finish"
                            class="btn-info disabled btn-finish">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- Include jQuery -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include jQuery Validator plugin -->
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Include SmartWizard JavaScript source -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    // Smart Wizard
                    $('#smartwizard').smartWizard(
                            {
                                selected : 0,
                                theme : 'dots',
                                transitionEffect : 'fade',
                                toolbarSettings : {
                                    toolbarPosition : 'bottom',
                                    toolbarExtraButtons : [

                                    {
                                        label : 'Cancel',
                                        css : 'btn-danger',
                                        onClick : function() {
                                            $('#smartwizard').smartWizard(
                                                    "reset");
                                            $('#myForm')
                                                    .find("input, textarea")
                                                    .val("");
                                        }
                                    } ]
                                }
                            });

                    $("#smartwizard")
                            .on(
                                    "showStep",
                                    function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber,
                                            stepDirection) {
                                        // Enable finish button only on last step
                                        if (stepNumber == 3) {
                                            $('.btn-finish').removeClass(
                                                    'disabled');
                                        } else {
                                            $('.btn-finish').addClass(
                                                    'disabled');
                                        }
                                    });

                });
    </script>

    <footer class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>Copyright Â© MyWebsite. All rights reserved.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

</body>
</html
```

Comment: i tryied your code, without any local css and without crawler.js.

Comment: why do you want tabs for just 4 fields?

Comment: so that it doesnt get congested. plus want to apply spliting form.... looks coool.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first assumption was, that you have used different forms for each tab. This was not true.

i tryied your code, without any local css and without crawler.js

**You need the submit button in order to submit the form**
or an ajax proccessing.

I changed the finish-button to be type="submit" an it worked. For testing i added dummy text "hizbk" in the email field. This prevented the submit, because the validation failed. But with correct data, form was submitted.

So you need to move the focus on the invalid form field/tab.

EDIT 1:
The reason why you can not submit is the html5 integrated validation.
Your document begins with the line  `<!DOCTYPE html>`, that means html5 document.

In the html5 there are many [new types of form fields](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions) as in previous html versions.

In your example you use type "email" and the field is "required":

`<input`**type="email"**`class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Write your email address"`**required**`>`

So in order to submit the email must be set (because of "requered") and must have a valid email syntax "something@domain.tld" 
*(The validity check is dependant on browser)*

EDIT 2:
To trigger partial validation after each step, you have to use a [jquery.smartWizard.js event](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Flexible-Bootstrap-Plugin-To-Create-Wizard-Style-Interface-Smart-Wizard.html#highlighter_956234) handler:

```
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber) {
    console.log(anchorObject);
    console.log(stepNumber);

    var containerId = '#form-step-' + stepNumber;
    var valid = true;

    $(containerId)
        // lets assume there are more than one form field in a tab
        .find('input, textarea, button, select')
        // for each of them check the validity
        .each(function(index, element) {
            console.log(element.name + ":");
            console.log(element.validity.valid ? "valid": "not valid");
            if (element.validity.valid == false) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    );
    // if something is not valid, false will be returned, which prevent the tab swiching.
    return valid;
    //return confirm("Do you want to leave the step "+stepNumber+"?");
});
```

You could check the fields validity like that and find a way to trigger the highlighting, if invalid...

*But we are faraway form the original question.

You should consider extending the topic of the question with something like:*
**partial form validation**

Comment: ok yes it is submitting. But one problem when i am not entering values and then clicking next next then at the last tab it doesnt submit.Any help on to make sure when user puts data in first tab then goes to next page or not.?